# How to make everything selectable?

Tags: select

I made a lot of objects unselectable (intentionally). Now, instead of un-clicking them one by one in the outliner I'd like a button like make *all objects selectable*. Can a Python script do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for scene objects:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.collection.all_objects:
    obj.hide_select = False
```

Or for all objects in the file:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.hide_select = False
```

Comment: Thank you! And sorry for too nonchalant editing my question ;)